# Calling to a non-object, where actually is an object

Tags: php

I have problem with php script.
The thing is that it shows me, that I am calling to a function of a non-object, but the object exists.

Script is:

```
if ($dcdt_sql['pdo']) {
try {
    $dbh = new PDO(
        'mysql:host='.$dcdt_sql[0].';dbname='.$dcdt_sql[3],
        $dcdt_sql[1],
        $dcdt_sql[2],
        array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
        )
    );
}
catch (PDOException $e) { die("PDO ERR: [".$e->getMessage()."]"); }
}
else { $dbh = DBManager::connect(); }

switch ($mode) {
case 'fetch_assoc':
    if ($dcdt_sql['pdo']) {
        try {
            $sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlQuery)->execute();
            $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // PROBLEM IS IN THIS LiNE
            $return = $result;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) { die("PDO ERR: [".$e->getMessage()."]"); }
    }
    else {
        $result = $dbh->query($sqlQuery);
                    if (!is_object($result)) { die('DEBUG: Query error: ['.$sqlQuery.'] returned: ['.print_r($result,1).']'); }//DEBUG
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $list[] = $row;
        }
        $return = $list;
    }
break;
```

Problem is where I commented it, but it should be an object whos function is called.
So I don't get it.

Error I get:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in /usr/local/www/apache22/data/centrs/dc_elec/report.lib.inc on line 102

Thank You in advance.

Comment: http://sg.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php `execute()` returns a boolean, so that error message is correct.

Comment: That's what you get for method chaining. Don't do it or you won't be able to spot errors like this easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sg.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Correct usage as dictated:

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

execute method returns TRUE or FALSE, not an object. Try

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlQuery);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlQuery);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // PROBLEM IS IN THIS LiNE
$return = $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // PROBLEM IS IN THIS LiNE
        $return = $result;
```

That should work, as execute will return a boolean, and not the object itself. In critique on the rest of the code; when you're working with objects, please look into *polymorphism*, those if/else statements should not be necessary if you put "the dirty work" into dedicated objects.